# Adaptive Triggers in Resource Dictionary

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10

I am trying to have a simple header of the page "adaptively" change the padding value based off of the width of the Page.  Namely I have a header TextBlock using a style from a Resource Dictionary as shown below:

```
<Style x:Key="PageHeaderStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
</Style>
```

In my page now I have a simple TextBlock that uses the Style from the Resource Dictionary above. In the page if I use the following code my adaptive triggers as shown below everything works:

```
    <Page
...
        Style="{StaticResource PageStyle}">

        <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Narrow">
                        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Target="PageHeader.Padding" Value="48,0,0,0" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Target="PageHeader.Padding" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Wide">
                        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1024"/>
                        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Target="PageHeader.Padding" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource GridHamburgerHeight}"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="14"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Border Background="{x:Bind Path=helper:CommonStyles.HamburgerPaneBackgroundColour}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderStyle}" Grid.Column="1" Text="HOME"/>
        </Grid>
    </Page>
```

My question is, how can I move that Adaptive VisualStateManager piece into the Style object within the Resource Dictionary itself so that I can re-use this header style and its "adaptive-ness" without having to paste the VisualStateManager on each page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've tried it's not possible to change page's template, seems to always use a default one. Therefore, taking into account that *VisualStateManager* must be in the root element of a *Control* - [source at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager#remarks):

> Control authors or app developers add VisualStateGroup object elements to the root element of a control template definition in XAML, using the VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups attached property.

you will probably have to create a custom *UserControl* or extend *Page* class - there you can add *VisualStateManager* and you won't have to repeat it all over, just use that control/page.

---

This is very simple example and should be extended, but it will give you a point to start (the source code you [can check at Github](https://github.com/Romasz/UWPSamples/tree/master/AdaptiveTriggerControl). For your case I would create a *TemplatedControl* - right click on your project in solution manager, then <kbd>Add</kbd>-><kbd>New Item</kbd>, then select <kbd>Templated Control</kbd>, lets name it *AdaptiveTriggerControl*, this should create a cs file and a *Generic.xaml* in *Themes* folder. Open the *AdaptiveTriggerControl.cs* file and modify the class it derives from - change from `Control` to `ContentControl`:

```cs
public sealed class AdaptiveTriggerControl : ContentControl
```

In *Generic.xaml* you define the control:

```xml
<Style TargetType="local:AdaptiveTriggerControl" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:AdaptiveTriggerControl">
                <Border x:Name="MyBorder"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <!--Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"-->
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Narrow">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="MyBorder.Background" Value="Red"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="MyBorder.Background" Value="Green"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Wide">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1024"/>
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="MyBorder.Background" Value="Blue"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then you can use it simply like this:

```xml
<local:AdaptiveTriggerControl>
    <TextBlock Text="Content of your page"/>
</local:AdaptiveTriggerControl>
```

[More information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/control-templates) about *TemplatedControls*, [a sample of creating *UserControl*](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Creating-Custom-Controls-a031a7ea).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and quick reply!  Do you have a good tutorial on how to do that using UserControls?  I've never done that before.

Comment: @sikhness I've put some more information and a sample in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!