# How to use VisualState AdaptiveTrigger to change ListView Item FontSize

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am using Visual State Adaptive Trigger to change page appearance depending on effective screen resolution. This works great, but I cannot get it to work for ListView Items.

My ListView looks something like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{Binding MyItem}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I can change the TextBlock font size statically in XAML. But I don't know how to reference this in VisualState setter target. Being automatically generated child, I cannot give TextBlock a name. My Visual State code is below. I've put ??? where I want to refer to ListView TextBlock item FontSize.

```
 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="NormalStateReadView">
                    <!-- VisualState to be triggered when window width is <720 effective pixels -->
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="???" Value="20" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>

    <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="NormalStateReadView">
                    <!-- VisualState to be triggered when window width is >=720 effective pixels -->
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="???" Value="30" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I can set the TextBlock's font size in Grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't use `AdaptiveTrigger` for an element inside the `DataTemplate`. You should use [UserControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.UserControl) to do it. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42614650/7331395) may help you. If you want a [video tutorial](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-042-Utilizing-User-Controls-as-Data-Templates) then this video may help you. But I have a little workaround for it.

**Here is my method:**

1. Create a `TextBlock` outside the `DataTemplate`and set `Visibility="Collapsed"`

   ```
   <TextBlock Name="SetFontSize" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
   ```

   **Note:** You could also use [`BindableValueHolder`](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/helpers/BindableValueHolder/) instead of this and set the Value property of it using `AdaptiveTrigger`.

   ```
   <helpers:BindableValueHolder x:Name="SetFontSize"/>
   ```
2. Use `AdaptiveTrigger` to change the `FontSize` of this `TextBlock`

   ```
   <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
       <VisualStateGroup>
           <VisualState x:Name="NormalStateReadView">
               <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                   <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
               </VisualState.StateTriggers>
               <VisualState.Setters>
                   <Setter Target="SetFontSize.FontSize" Value="20" />
               </VisualState.Setters>
           </VisualState>
       </VisualStateGroup>

       <VisualStateGroup>
           <VisualState x:Name="WideStateReadView">
               <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                   <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
               </VisualState.StateTriggers>
               <VisualState.Setters>
                   <Setter Target="SetFontSize.FontSize" Value="30" />
               </VisualState.Setters>
           </VisualState>
       </VisualStateGroup>
   </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
   ```
3. DataBind the `FontSize` of the `TextBlock` inside the `DataTemplate` to the outer `TextBlock`

   ```
   <TextBlock FontSize="{Binding Path=FontSize, ElementName=SetFontSize}"/>
   ```

**Here is your code:**

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState x:Name="NormalStateReadView">
            <!-- VisualState to be triggered when window width is <720 effective pixels -->
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="SetFontSize.FontSize" Value="20" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>

    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState x:Name="WideStateReadView">
            <!-- VisualState to be triggered when window width is >=720 effective pixels -->
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="SetFontSize.FontSize" Value="30" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

<TextBlock Name="SetFontSize" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
<ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock FontSize="{Binding Path=FontSize, ElementName=SetFontSize}" Text="{Binding MyItem}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: very nice and elegant solution. Thanks so much!

Comment: I have to say, this feels a bit hacky to me. :) But I respect the reason given by the OP.

Comment: @JustinXL I like to have all the VisualStateManager at first.

Comment: But what if you need to modify more than just the font size? I think we both need a better solution here.

Comment: @JustinXL Can we modified `ResourceDictionary` by `AdaptiveTrigger`?

Answer (score 5):

You will need to wrap your your template inside a `UserControl` for adaptive triggers to work; also the visual states should go inside the template as well, and make sure it's under the first direct child (i.e. `Grid`) of the `UserControl`. I see you have defined two visual state groups but really you just need one.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <UserControl>
            <Grid>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="Title.(TextBlock.FontSize)" Value="24" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>

                        <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="Title.(TextBlock.FontSize)" Value="36" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                <TextBlock x:Name="Title" Text="{Binding Property1}" />
            </Grid>
        </UserControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

---

### Update

Here is what I think a much more flexible solution. It needs some code to setup but the outcome is that you get clean, reusable and readable code.

The idea is to obtain a reference of the top level `VisualStateGroup` which is defined *outside* of the `ListView`, mostly at the `Page` level.

Then, create three `VisualState`s (i.e. *Narrow*, *Normal* & *Wide*) and attach them to a new `VisualStateGroup` which should belong to the first child of the `UserControl`.

Once we have referenced these two `VisualStateGroup`s, we can monitor the top level one's `CurrentStateChanged` and update the state in the second one accordingly.

All the logic above can be wrapped by a `Behavior` from the [UWP XAML Behavior nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed/).

Once the [`Behavior`](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/VisualStateAndDataTemplate/blob/master/VisualStateAndDataTemplate/VisualStateInTemplateBehavior.cs) in place, you can define your inner states as easy as -

```
<DataTemplate>
    <UserControl>
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:VisualStateInTemplateBehavior ParentVisualStateGroup="{Binding ElementName=AdaptiveVisualStates}">
                <local:VisualStateInTemplateBehavior.NarrowState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Narrow">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Target="Title.(TextBlock.FontSize)" Value="24" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </local:VisualStateInTemplateBehavior.NarrowState>

                <local:VisualStateInTemplateBehavior.NormalState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Target="Title.(TextBlock.FontSize)" Value="32" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </local:VisualStateInTemplateBehavior.NormalState>

                <local:VisualStateInTemplateBehavior.WideState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Wide">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Target="Title.(TextBlock.FontSize)" Value="40" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </local:VisualStateInTemplateBehavior.WideState>
            </local:VisualStateInTemplateBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

---

### Working Demo

[image]

---

Feel free to check out a working sample [here](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/VisualStateAndDataTemplate).

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I accepted the first solution. I prefer to have visual states defined for the page and resize everything in one place.

Comment: (OR) We could use [`BindableValueHolder`](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/helpers/BindableValueHolder/)

Comment: Is there any documentation that says you need to wrap it in  "UserControl" how are we meant to know that ?