# VisualStates not working inside UWP FlipView

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

In my FlipView, I have VisualState triggers set up in the DataTemplate to show/hide Grids based on window width. The triggers inside the DataTemplate work fine when outside of the FlipView, but when I put the Grid inside of the FlipView DataTemplage, the triggers never fire. I've used this technique in ListView without issue, so not sure what's different here.

```
<FlipView>
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualState>
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="View1.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                <Setter Target="View2.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState>
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="700" />
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="View1.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                <Setter Target="View2.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Grid x:Name="View1"></Grid>
                <Grid x:Name="View2"></Grid>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

Comment: Can you post correct FlipView, I see the code is missing tags. This is basically incomplete xaml code.

Comment: yes, it has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual states don't work inside a `DataTemplate` unless the top level container is a `Control`(Check out the *first parameter* in `VisualStateManager.GoToState()` which is called under the hood). In your case, it's a `Grid` so it won't work.

An easy workaround is to **wrap your `Grid` inside a `UserControl`, or a `ContentControl` with an empty style** (see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088500/adaptivetrigger-and-datatemplate/32092547#32092547)).

If you already have this set of visual states defined at your *Page* level and would like the same rules applied to some `DataTemplate`s within the page. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751821/how-to-use-visualstate-adaptivetrigger-to-change-listview-item-fontsize/44753148#44753148) where I used a `Behavior` to pass the `VisualStateGroup` reference down instead of duplicating them in order to keep all `MinWindowWidth` settings in one place.